# Radio app on Windows Phone 8

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, tile, shoutcast

I start developing Windows Phone 8 apps recently. I'm trying to do an app for a local radio. They use Shoutcast for internet broadcasting.

But I see that WP doesn't have native shoutcast support. So I searched for implementation for Shoutcast. I found http://shoutcastmss.codeplex.com/ and start working on it.

I succeeded to play shoutcast but I want to do a live tile that shows current song. But due to restrictions on Windows Phone 8, I need to upgrade my project to Windows Phone 8.1 to update live tiles more often.

My project is based on Windows Phone Silverlight 8.0. Thanks(!) to Microsoft, BackgroundAudioPlayer class is no more available for Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1.

So,

Is there a way to use BackgroundAudioPlayer in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1?

Or

If I have to make it a Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime App, How can I do that?

Or

Can I keep it as a Windows Phone Silverlight 8.0 app, but update the live tile every minute? (User will have WP 8.1)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it'll work for WP Silverlight 8.1. As for working with [BackgroundAudioPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.backgroundaudioplayer(v=vs.105).aspx) is a limitation in Windows Phone [Silverlight 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn642084(v=vs.105).aspx). Therefore you will have to write an app that targets WP8.0 Silverlight or WP8.1 WinRt app.

You could refer here for more:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c9275491-cfff-4078-bc6d-6debe5372790/backgroundaudioplayer-is-not-working-after-upgrading-windows-phone-8-apps-to-windows-phone?forum=wpdevelop

Hope it helps!